# NX configuration: After NX upgrade getting: ` > NX Unable to resolve @nx/node:webpack.`

Tags: nrwl-nx, nrwl, nomachine-nx

Running basic express app, nothing crazy, everything worked on NX 15.
After upgrade and standard:

```
 nx migrate latest
 nx migrate --run-migrations
 rm -rf node_modules
 npm i
```

getting this error:

```
> nx run api:serve --port 3000 --inspect


 >  NX   Unable to resolve @nx/node:webpack.

   Cannot find executor 'webpack' in  ...\node_modules\@nx\node\executors.json.
```

..\node_modules@nx\node\executors.json looks like this:

```json
{
  "executors": {
    "node": {
      "implementation": "./src/executors/node/node.impl",
      "schema": "./src/executors/node/schema.json",
      "description": "Execute a Node application."
    }
  },
  "builders": {
    "node": {
      "implementation": "./src/executors/node/compat",
      "schema": "./src/executors/node/schema.json",
      "description": "Execute a Node application."
    }
  }
}
```

and project.json looks like this:

```json
{
  "name": "api",
  "$schema": "..\\..\\node_modules\\nx\\schemas\\project-schema.json",
  "sourceRoot": "apps/api/src",
  "projectType": "application",
  "targets": {
    "build": {
      "executor": "@nx/node:webpack",
      "outputs": ["{options.outputPath}"],
      "options": {
        "outputPath": "dist/apps/api",
        "main": "apps/api/src/server.ts",
        "tsConfig": "apps/api/tsconfig.app.json",
        "assets": ["apps/api/src/assets"]
      },
      "configurations": {
        "production": {
          "optimization": true,
          "extractLicenses": true,
          "inspect": false,
          "fileReplacements": [
            {
              "replace": "apps/api/src/environments/environment.ts",
              "with": "apps/api/src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    },
    "serve": {
      "executor": "@nx/node:node",
      "options": {
        "buildTarget": "api:build"
      },
      "configurations": {
        "production": {
          "buildTarget": "api:build:production"
        }
      }
    },
    "lint": {
      "executor": "@nx/linter:eslint",
      "outputs": ["{options.outputFile}"],
      "options": {
        "lintFilePatterns": ["apps/api/**/*.ts"]
      }
    },
    "test": {
      "executor": "@nx/jest:jest",
      "outputs": ["{workspaceRoot}/coverage/apps/api"],
      "options": {
        "jestConfig": "apps/api/jest.config.ts",
        "passWithNoTests": true
      }
    }
  },
  "tags": []
}
```

Both commands `nx build` and `nx serve` throw webpack error. Not sure what is the fix here
Let me know if you need more details

**Update: Solution bellow**

I just simply  created another node/express app and copied all the files from API app to NEW_API..

```
# create new
nx g @nx/express:app new-api --frontendProject client

# remove old
nx g @nx/workspace:rm api

# rename
nx g mv --project new-api api
```

that's it, no issues with running NEW_API...

*...sorry if my lack of interest to trying to resolve this disappoints you =)*

Comment: If you can share your the github repo It would really help but if you can't can you also shared your `package.json`

Comment: Thanks for your interest, I actually found a workaround and an easy fix essentially. Please see the update

Comment: Running into this same issue as well

Answer (score 1):

the executor for serve is now @nx/js:node while the build should be @nx/webpack:webpack

reference:
https://github.com/nrwl/nx/issues/15903#issuecomment-1539976285